# sending an ssh -t command to multiple systems simultaneously (without ansible)

Tags: bash, ssh, command, simultaneous, hosts-file

Because of the nature of the script (done at work, on a work RHEL machine) I cannot show the code, but I can at least provide pseudocode to help with a starting point.  Currently:

start loop

1) read in the first line of a host text file (then the next and such per 
          the loop) of a file and assign it to a variable (host name)

2) send ssh -t command to the host (which takes anywhere between 2 to 6 
          minutes to receive a response back)

3) log response to a text file (repeat loop with new host from read in 
          text file)

end loop

Currently I have to run this script over night because of how many systems this script hits.

I want to be able to achieve the same goal and get the response from the command in that file per host, but I want the command to be sent out at the same time so that it takes anywhere between 2 to 6 minutes all together.
But because this is for work, I am not allowed to install ansible on the system; would there be another way to achieve this goal?  If so please provide some areas or point me in the right direction.

Comment: gnu-parallel or append a simple `&`?

Comment: `&` is the best option. Psuedocode answer: `ssh $hostname "somecommand >./locallogfile" &` in a loop, then `scp` the ./locallogfiles to your main system 2-6 minutes later.

Comment: @jeremysprofile probably should use >> to write the file here

Comment: @Inder, why? If he only wants the output of this command, each logfile for the remote systems should use `>`. He'll have to `scp` and `cat` once he moves them to his main system. I'll admit that I probably should have named it `remotelogfile` to be more clear, but it won't let me edit the comment anymore.

Comment: @jeremysprofile won't > just keep overwriting the same file over and over again for all the attempts ?

Comment: @Inder, he wants to connect to a bunch of different systems. each `ssh $hostname` call will be to a different value of `$hostname`.

Comment: *I am not allowed to install ansible*  instead of reinventing the wheel by introducing a ton of race conditions and bad timeout handlings you should ask where this rule comes from and why (not necessarily for this specific tool but any of its kind, you have in the same way `chef`, `puppet`, or libraries like `fabric` in Python, etc...) by explaining that this would do a far better job than any local homegrown solution. I am sure they did not write the local `bash` and `ssh` but installed them from outside, so why forbidding other tools that are relevant to the job?

Comment: I'm with @PatrickMevzek here, using Bash is not wrong, it's just too long. Tools Chef, Puppet or SaltStack are the best tools for this kind of things as they use fast messaging bus like Redis to communicate between master and slave. You should question your superiors on why you need to reinvent the wheel rather than getting on with it.

Comment: @jeremysprofile I appreciate the psuedocode answer you provided, let me modify that to at least sort of mimic the command itself within the loop.  
Below is the line that is following in the loop where $i is each system in the read in file, which is about 80 systems.  

ssh -t $i "command being sent to system $i" | grep ___ >> "text-file-to-save-GREPed-response.txt" 

With that line of code where would the & go?

Comment: your idea will not work. returning output to your local machine will cause garbage ordering with concurrent commands. As my comment said, you need to save the output of the command on the remote system, then scp all outputs to your local system.

Comment: @Praveen P
I can only use what is already available to me, I am not allowed to explain due to our contract with the customer.  Just understand that the main reason I can only use what is already available to me is because these systems I am running this data gathering command against cannot be changed from the current configuration due to our contract agreement.  So I can not make any changes to those systems, only gather data from them which is basically the nature of this command.  Otherwise I could have already achieved this goal with ansible.

Comment: @jeremysprofile
Ok, I will make those modifications and get back with you.  If the only change is where the text file of each response goes and I need to scp them after the script is done, to me that is a small price to pay for saving time (which is my current issue with this script).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j0 --slf hosts.txt --nonall mycommand > out.txt
```

But maybe you want a bit more info:

```
parallel -j0 --slf hosts.txt --joblog my.log --tag --nonall mycommand > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using `sh` years ago using something like:

```
while true
do
   if [ numberOfFileinSomeDir -lt N ]
   then
      (touch SomeDir/hostname; ssh hostname ... > someotherDir/hostname.txt ; rm SomeDir/hostname) &
      ...
```

But this stops working after ~100 hosts. It sucks - don't do it. If less than about ~500 hosts [pssh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/) may be the easiest - maybe you can install in your home directory?

Google something like `python parallel execute process multiple` and someone's bound to have a script that will do what you need already.

More than ~500 hosts and you *really* need to start installing some tools as others have mentioned in the comments.